# Is it possible to run zeppelin with spark yarn-cluster

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

It runs well with spark yarn-client but what about yarn-cluster? If it's possible then please share how we can do that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible in current master version of Zeppelin.

Check out 
https://medium.com/@zjffdu/zeppelin-0-8-0-new-features-ea53e8810235

Yarn Cluster Mode for Spark Interpreter

Before 0.8.0, Zeppelin only supported yarn client mode for Spark Interpreter which means the driver would run in the same host of Zeppelin Server. The incur high memory pressure of the Zeppelin Server host especially when you run Spark Interpreter in isolated mode.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2898 (merged to master end of Sep/2017).

Update: Notice 0.8.0 is released which has this feature in.

Answer (score 0):

Currently zeppelin does not support yarn cluster, only yarn-client.
What would be the usecase for this?

Comment: The reason being, every time zeppelin needs restart, executors gets killed and hence cache is lost. To avoid this behavior, spark should run as yarn-cluster so that driver run in application master.

Comment: to add to your comment, yarn-cluster manages all the JARs from HDFS without locally copying them which takes twice the time to create a new spark session.